# Return to React-Native application after initiating a phone call with the linking interface

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, deep-linking

I've added the ability to initiate a phone call from within my React-Native application running on both iOS and Android. I do this using the linking interface provided by React-Native similar to below.

```
const url = 'tel:5684567854';

Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
  if (!supported) {
    console.log('Can\'t handle url: ' + url);
  } else {
    return Linking.openURL(url);
  }
}).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
```

My question is how can I be automatically returned to my application after the phone call is ended? At this point when the call is finished, I am left on the iOS and Android phone application.

Is that possible initiating the call with this method?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible on Android.  The dialer application is an application.  It would need to choose to end itself, and there is no option to force it to do so.  (For that matter its not even the same app on every android device, so there would need to be a standard way to do it across all apps, which doesn't exist).